# Group by either column

Tags: mysql

Sample Table:

```
User1 | User2
------+------
123   | 555
123   | 1
123   | 2
456   | 2
555   | 456
12    | 123
12    | 456
```

Input: I enter the list `(123,456)` to look at rows containing either of those values. Then I want MySQL to check the opposite/other column in that row, and group the output by that value.

Output:

```
User | Count(*)
-----+---------
555  | 2
2    | 2
1    | 1
```

555 count is 2 because row `123, 555` and row `555, 456` both contain one of the inputs: 123 and 456.

I've tried looking at the `CASE` keyword, because the obvious obstacle here is grabbing the opposite/remaining column and using that as one of the returned values.

Completely wrong, but one of my half-finished approaches.

```
SELECT user, count(*)
FROM friendships
WHERE User1 IN (123,456) AS user 
   OR User2 IN (123,456) AS user
```

Comment: Try using nested queries with the inner query being a union of two queries each with a group by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the tricky part with this is your criteria is the IN() is looking in the users1 column and then tries to find duplicates in the user2 column... so you need a join with a UNION

```
SELECT user2, COUNT(*)
FROM
(   SELECT user1, user2
    FROM friends f
    WHERE f.user1 IN(123, 456)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT f.user1, f.user2
    FROM friends f
    JOIN friends f1 ON f1.user1 = f.user2
    WHERE f.user1 IN(123, 456)
)t
GROUP BY user2;
```

[**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5866/2)